# Mysql - Get data from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables webadstats and webstatsclick and i want to make below query from these two tables.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT
    count(*) as 'impressions',
    unix_timestamp(date(from_unixtime(A.time))) as 'timestamp',
    COUNT(B.click) as 'clickss'
FROM `webadstats` as A
LEFT JOIN `webstatsclick` as B
ON A.pubadhash = B.pubadhash
WHERE A.pubadhash='$pubadhash'
GROUP BY date(from_unixtime(A.time))";

$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result2)>0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        $impressions[] = $row['impressions'];
        $clicksall[] = $row['clickss'];
        $timestamp[] = $row['timestamp'];
    }

     for($i=0; $i<count($clicksall); $i++){
    $str .= $timestamp[$i] . '||' . $impressions[$i] . '||' . $clicksall[$i]  ."\n";
    }

}

echo $str;
```

But the problem is that this query is generating same values for both the variables impressions and clickss out of which value of impressions variable is correct.

```
1542434400||1270||1270
1542520800||1800||1800
1542607200||1745||1745
1542693600||1805||1805
1542780000||1615||1615
1542866400||1740||1740
1542952800||1740||1740
1543039200||1830||1830
1543125600||1830||1830
1543212000||1615||1615
1543298400||1880||1880
1543384800||2125||2125
1543471200||1530||1530
1543557600||1370||1370
1543644000||120||120
```

My both the DB structure is
webadstats db

[webadstats db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbq2E.jpg)

webstatsclick db

[webstatsclick db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vl2p2.jpg)

Kindly help me where i am wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you want count DISTINCT somethings

Comment: Did you try count(B.visitorip) as I suggested in your previous question?

Comment: yes i tried count(B.visitorip) but same problem persists

Comment: What happens if you change `ON A.pubadhash = B.pubadhash` to `ON A.session = B.session` ?

Comment: Did you check that the values are different in the database?

Comment: Jared it tried this but this shows data only for users who clicked ads but not for other users but the good thing is that this is producing different values for both click and impressions

Comment: @SeReGa yes values are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go back to the two query approach. The problem is, we've been trying to use JOIN on pubadhash but also WHERE with pubadhash, so the values get multiplied.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT
    count(*) as 'impressions',
    unix_timestamp(date(from_unixtime(time))) as 'timestamp'
FROM `webadstats`
WHERE pubadhash='$pubadhash'
GROUP BY date(from_unixtime(time))";

$sql3 = "SELECT
    count(*) as 'clickss',
    unix_timestamp(date(from_unixtime(time))) as 'timestamp'
FROM `webstatsclick`
WHERE pubadhash='$pubadhash'
GROUP BY date(from_unixtime(time))";

$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result2)>0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        $arr[$row['timestamp']]['impressions'] = $row['impressions'];
        $arr[$row['timestamp']]['timestamp'] = $row['timestamp'];
        $arr[$row['timestamp']]['clickss'] = 0;
    }

    $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result3)>0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
            $arr[$row['timestamp']]['clickss'] = $row['clickss'];
        }
    }

    foreach($arr as $clicks){
        $str .= $clicks['timestamp'] . '||' . $clicks['impressions'] . '||' . $clicks['clickss']  ."\n";
    }

}

echo $str;
```

Comment: almost working but not producing values of clicks, showing only blank space check https://prnt.sc/lpb1tt

Comment: Sorry, typo. Change `$arr[$row['timestamp']]['clickss'] = $row['impressions'];` to `$arr[$row['timestamp']]['clickss'] = $row['clickss'];` And if it finally works, please don't forget to click the Checkmark next to my answer to give us both rep